# How to parse data using an ASN.1 decoder using the DER encoding rules?

Tags: android

I am writing one of Android application which communicates with hardware device.
Hardware device sends data on server socket registered port number.
I am reciving data in application but that need to be parsed using ASN.1 decoder and needs to apply DER encoding rules to that.

I dont have any idea how it can be done.

So please guide me towards solution for this parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an introduction to ASN.1, [several](http://www.obj-sys.com/asn1tutorial/asn1only.html) [different](http://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/introduction.aspx) [introductions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/252648) and [books](http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/books-whitepapers-pubs/asn1-books.html) are available. (The Microsoft link describes BER in a little detail; DER is a proper subset of BER.)

Most ASN.1 tools, like the [freely-available one from Lev Walkin](http://lionet.info/asn1c/blog/) and commercial options from (among others) [Objective Systems](http://www.obj-sys.com/products/asn1c/) and [OSS Nokalva](http://www.oss.com) provide two components: a compiler to translate ASN.1 specifications into source code, and runtime libraries that this generated source code calls to perform encoding and decoding.

You generally have a choice when you want to do Android development with ASN.1: if you develop in Java, you can (possibly) translate Java runtime libraries from the commercial options (I don't think that [Lev's ASN1C](http://lionet.info/asn1c/blog/) supports Java) into DEX using Android tools, or you can acquire a native runtime library; I know for sure that [Objective Systems](http://www.obj-sys.com/products/asn1c/) supports both (having worked there).

If you're working with a restricted syntax (e.g., because you want to parse security certificates), you may be able to find other options; I'm not terribly familiar with the libraries, but [BouncyCastle](http://bouncycastle.org/) is commonly mentioned on StackOverflow.

Good luck!